# Android - OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED is true but isObbMounted() is false, what is wrong?

Tags: android, storage, mount

I have an extension file under "/sdcard/Android/obb/com.example.obbtest/vid-exp1.obb". It contains an MP4 file and I want to mount the .obb to read the file.

This is what I'm doing to mount it:

```
String obbDir = "/sdcard/Android/obb/com.example.obbtest/vid-exp1.obb";
```

.

```
StorageManager storage = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
storage.mountObb(obbDir, null, listener);
```

This is the listener code:

```
OnObbStateChangeListener listener = new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
            public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
                if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                    toastString("Mounted! According to the listener");
                    //Test it with the isObbMounted()
                    if (storage.isObbMounted(obbDir)) {
                        toastString("Efectively mounted!");
                    } else {
                        toastString("Not really :(");
                    }
                    toastString(storage.getMountedObbPath(obbDir));
                } else {
                    tuestameString("NOT mounted according to the listener");
                } 
            }
        };
```

Unfortunately the output I get is a toast saying "Mounted! According to the listener" followed by "Not really :(". I designed this test because when I tried getMountedObbPath(obbDir) I got a null String instead of the path. I've made sure the .obb file exists and all that, without it or without the correct encription key I don'get "Mounted!...".

I don't understand why  OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED is true but isObbMounted(obbDir) false. Does anyone know what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem on a Samsung device. It happens when `/mnt/sdcard/` is not a directory but a symlink to another dir (in my case that was `/storage/sdcard0`).

In this case `StorageManager` uses not the path to the obb that you have specified, but the path with symlinks resolved: `isObbMounted("/mnt/sdcard/my.obb")` returns `false` and `isObbMounted("/storage/sdcard0/my.obb")` is `true`.

To access the mounted obb, you must not use the path obbDir, but the path passed to `onObbStateChange()` in the first argument: `isObbMounted(path)`.